# pass data to background activity without change the current activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 activity. 
Activiy A will list links to download.
Activity B has a listview of download item.
When I click the link in activity A, how to send the link to activity B to download without change activity A (while activity B still downloading on background) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that Activities Dont need any result to work, activities need data. And Activities can use these data to load contents of its. And there is no use of this data into activity untill its into background. SO Here is solution:

1. Create some Data ArrayList or Flag, Global to the application.
2. Changes this Data into Second activity, which is in forground, and want to notify about some result.
3. When First Activity which is in background, and want to listen results, check for changes into data in onResume method, and on change load new contents.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

> Activity A: Shows a list of items to download.
>
> Service B: Downloads the item in the background. Maybe you can queue
>   multiple download items.
>
> File C: When you finish downloading something you should save that
>   fact in a file.
>
> Activity D: When this activity starts it should read 'File C' and
>   display its contents.

You can't really send data to an Activity without starting it. When an Activity is not visible it is pretty much asleep.

You should read this: [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html), read it many many times ... then read it again. I still go back and read it after years of working with Android.